# circleci docker's mysql and php images failing on creation

Tags: docker, testing, yaml, circleci

My `.circleci/config.yml` have the next structure:

```
defaults: &defaults
  docker:
    - image: circleci/node:lts-stretch
    - image: circleci/php:7.1-apache-node-browsers
    - image: circleci/mysql:8.0.4
      environment:
        MYSQL_HOST: 127.0.0.1
        MYSQL_DB: rpgjs_test
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: rpgjs_test_password
  working_directory: ~/repo
```

But the image creation keeps failing and throws the next errors:

**PHP**

```
$ _XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.


Build was canceled
```

**Mysql**

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 
'root'@'%'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`root` user exists by default and cannot be recreated.

Try to set `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` and remove `MYSQL_PASSWORD` and `MYSQL_USER`

Comment: This removed that particular error but it is the build is being cancelled with the next message: `Build was canceled`. It is displaying a huge series of messages before that, should i add it to my question?